# Remove duplicity in DataFrames (peers)

Tags: python, duplicates

I'm trying to remove duplicate elements in a dataframe. This DataFrame comes from calculating the distance between a given list of geocoordinates. As you can see in the following DataFrame, the data is duplicated but I can't set the index to 'dist' because in other cases, the distance might be 0 or 1 (repeated) and then important data will be discarded.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name_x':['a','b','c','d'],
            'Name_y':['b','a','d','c'],
            'Latitude_x':['lat_a','lat_b','lat_c','lat_d'],
            'Longitude_x':['long_a','long_b','long_c','long_d'],
            'Latitude_y':['lat_b','lat_a','lat_d','lat_c'],
            'Longitude_y':['long_b','long_a','long_d','long_c'],
            'dist':[0,0,1,1]})
df
```

In this case I would like to remain with the values Name_x: ['a','c'], Name_y['b','d'] with the corresponding geocoordinates: Latitude_x:['lat_a','lat_c'], Latitude_y:['lat_b','lat_d'], Longitude_x:['long_a','long_c'], Longitude_y: ['long_b','long_d'].

Comment: Did you merge two dataframes to get this result?

Comment: Exactly, in order to cross every geocoordinate with the others.

Comment: Maybe a join isn't what you need?

Comment: How could I implement it with a join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you want this:

```
df['Name_x'].eq(df['Name_y'].shift()) # filter by equals for name

df.loc[df['Name_x'].eq(df['Name_y'].shift())] # Your "unique" rows
```